# Google calendar iFrame sometimes doesn't load

Tags: html, iframe, google-calendar-api

I have three calendars on my website via iFrame, but sometimes they don't load.
For example - two of three show up, but the third one doesn't show up or css style is missing.
I tried using debugger in Chrome and it throws an error/s
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for *.js and *.css too.

Is there a way how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. But you cant fix this problem. Google Calender some times get error because of site issues, like editing their site or fixing some errors etc. While doing this,Google Calender's server shut downs, and error occurs in users sites.